# Own exception in javame

Tags: java, java-me, exception

Could I replace all the catches with one (self written) catch and switch between the types of exceptions caught in the self written one? That way I can easily put debugging on and of in the exception.

```
try {
            int recordId = recordstore.addRecord(data, 0, data.length);

        } catch (RecordStoreFullException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("debuginfo");
        } catch (RecordStoreNotOpenException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("debuginfo");
        } catch (RecordStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("debuginfo");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("debuginfo");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("debuginfo");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you don't do this?

```
try {
    int recordId = recordstore.addRecord(data, 0, data.length);

} catch (Exception e) {
    // or use a logging framework.
    System.err.println("debuginfo");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Because I wan't to have the specifik exception information. I could switch between e.getMessage() in a general Exception, but that's too general

Comment: Can you update your example? You say you want to replace all your catchs but you haven't shown what is preventing you from doing so.

Comment: yes but can you replace them all with a custom Exception you wrote yourself?

Comment: How would that help?  You could change addRecord to have a custom exception (not in code shown) or you could thrown a custom exception extracting the information you need from each exception (or you could just wrap it)

Comment: The benefit would be I don't have to delete all the System.out.println commands (In my program it's replaced with a logging framework which takes a lot of resources so I can't leave it on). But if I use my own Exception I could use a boolean to debug the exception or not. Only put the debug boolean on false and there will be no more debug information.

Comment: The effort in doing this is likely to be more than what you save. You shouldn't have so many exceptions that the debug information is worth turning off. I would still print out all the information I can when an exception occurs because it should occurr so rarely.